# Get a views results programatically

Tags: views, 8

I have a page with a view on it and some exposed inputs. I need to get the results programatically. I can load a view programmatically no problem but setting the exposed input has not been working.

```
$view = Views::getView('inventory_listing');
$view->initDisplay();
$view->setExposedInput($view->getExposedInput());
$view->preExecute();
$view->execute();
```

results in ALL the rows, not the ones filtered out. I am running this in my hook_form_alter function because I need to change the display of my exposed filters. That may be part of the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I use direct input parameter for right filtering, and it is working for me.

```
$view = Views::getView('my_view_name');
$view->setDisplay('display_name_from_my_view');
$view->setArguments([ $value1, $value2 ]);
$view->execute();
```

So, i can take result of $view by

```
$result = [];
if (empty($view->build_info['fail']) and empty($view->build_info['denied'])) {
    $result = $view->result;
}
```

After this I can render it or use for another goal.